# Django Custom Querysets

Tags: django, django-models

Using the usual Django model as an example, I'm trying to view with a table of authors where I can sort by their number of books.  Creating the book count as a model method (as below) works fine for the display, but that rules out sorting by that 'field' in the queryset:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()

    def book_count(self):
        return Book.objects.filter(author=self).count()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

I know I could post-queryset sorting, but I'm also applying Django pagination, so retrieving all the records would presumably have a performance hit..

I think adding [Manager Methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods) is the answer, but I'm struggling to make it work:

```
class AuthorManager(models.Manager):
    def book_count(self):
        return Books.objects.filter(author=self).count()

class Author(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    objects = AuthorManager()
```

My django template is not returning anything.  Is the problem the construction of the manager above, or how to call it in the template?
I've assumed it would just be (this works for my model method above, but not for a manager method):

```
{% for author in authors %}
    {{ author.book_count }}
{% endif %}
```

Ultimately this is all about me wanting to write a queryset like this:

```
queryset = authors.objects.all().order_by('book_count')
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Using an aggregate

Well here your `book_count` is a function that is defined on the model. But the *database layer* does not know anything about such functions: it only knows something about the fields, and some elements of the `Meta` class (like `unique_together`, etc.). Since Python is typically more expressive than SQL there are not much hopes that Django itself will - in the (near) future - encode such properties as SQL queries (or any other database management system).

What we thus have to do is **translate the query into an aggregate** and then sort on that aggregate.

We can use `.annotate` to first annotate all authors with the number of books they have written, and then sort on that count:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Author.objects.annotate(book_count=Count('book_set')).order_by('book_count')
```

This is a queryset that will sort the authors by the number of books from the least amount to the largest amount. We can use `'-book_count'` to sort in reverse order.

Something that is also nice is that you can access this aggregate. So an `Author` instance that is the result of this query (not any other query, the annotation has to be done), carries a `book_count` attribute that stores the result of the aggregate.

Django will thus translate this query in something like:

```
SELECT `author`.`id`, `author`.`first_name`, `author`.`last_name`,
       COUNT(`book`.`id`) AS `book_count`
FROM `author`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `book` ON (`author`.`id` = `book`.`author_id`)
GROUP BY `author`.`id`
ORDER BY `book_count` ASC
```

So we perform an aggregate with a `GROUP BY` to annotate all authors with the number of books they wrote. The sorting is thus done entirely at the *database level* which is typically faster than doing this at the application level.

## Encapsulate the logic in a `Manager`

We can inject this in a custom queryset manager with:

```
class AuthorManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(AuthorManager, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.annotate(book_count=Count('book_set'))
```

We here thus construct a custom manager for `Author`, we can now attach it to the `Author` model with:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()

    objects = AuthorManager()
```

Now we can obtain the `Author` objects sorted according to `book_count` with:

```
Author.objects.order_by('book_count')
```

Comment: That's great, thank you very much.  I knew I was close - it was continuing to query the author model (rather than book) in the AuthorManager using the annotate option that was escaping me.  Much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `annotate` with custom QuerySet class:

```
from djano.dm.models import Count

class AuthorQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def annotated(self):
        return self.annotate(books_count=Count('book_set'))

class AuthorManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return AuthorQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def annotated(self):
        return self.get_queryset().annotated()

class Author(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    objects = AuthorManager()
```

Now to order by books count you can use this query:

```
 Author.object.annotated().order_by('books_count')
```

To get annoted count in template use:

```
{{ author.books_count }}
```

Comment: That's great, thank you very much.  I knew I was close - it was continuing to query the author model (rather than book) in the AuthorManager using the annotate option that was escaping me.  Much appreciated :-)